# How to know whether the viewcenter conincide with other view center?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I have a scroll view and a subview(which is UIView) and am just wanted to know whether the view is in center of the scrollview. I was just trying to compare the view.center for both but which are not equal. Please let me know if there are any other possible approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following comparison(Xcode 9.3 with Swift4.1):

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    let centerSubView = scrollView.convert(subView.center, to: scrollView.superview)

    //Convert CGFloat to Int to avoid decimal problem before comparison
    if Int(centerSubView.x) == Int(scrollView.center.x) && Int(centerSubView.y) == Int(scrollView.center.y) {
        print("equal center")
    }
}
```